# GCC ARM How to assign value to particular fp register using inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly

I have trouble to assign value to particular fp register.

For example, If I use general register it compiles and works fine:

```
register uint* r1   asm ("r1") = (uint *) lrd;
```

but when I try to do the same for fp register:

```
register float f3   asm ("f3") = 1.0;
```

I'm getting this error during compilation:

```
error: register specified for ‘f3’ isn’t suitable for data type
```

I used following command line to compile my kernel:

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon c_class.c
```

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f3` is legacy FPA register naming, and I couldn't find any way to make the cross-compiler I have handy (GCC 4.8.3) *not* choke on it, albeit with a slightly different message:

```
test.c:5:17: error: invalid register name for ‘f’
  register float f asm("f3") = 42.0;
```

Using the up-to-date VFP/NEON designation `s3`:

```
 register float f asm("s3") = 42.0;
```

worked fine and produced a disassembly that looked sane:

```
 4:   eddf 1a03       vldr    s3, [pc, #12]   ; 14 <main+0x14>
...
14:   42280000        .word   0x42280000
```

It also seems to accept specifying a double-precision register view (`d3`) without complaint, although that still compiled to a 32-bit load to the equivalent single-precision register (`s6`).

Comment: I used wrong cross-compiler (GCC 4.7.3) for soft float (armel) and AMRv4 architecture instead of using a cross-compiler for hard float (armhf) and ARMv7. It works fine with GCC 4.8.2 and  the up-to-date VFP/NEON designation (s or d).